# How to tell the program to do something at exact time every day?

Tags: python, windows, time, runtime

I'm working on a Python program which will be running on users computer. The program should be idle as much as possible between actions (3 per day). Actions should be at morning, afternoon and in the night.

So I want to tell the program that it has to run (to instantiate a class and do some methods from it) at three certain times every day.

I know about one way but it is an overkill I think.

```
while True:
    time = time.now()
    if time in [08:00 am, 12:30pm, 08:00 pm]:
        #Do what you have to do
```

Can you advise me the best approach to program like this? This program will run not on my computer so I would like to manage everything as a one component.

EDIT: Martin advise me to use cron job. Is it possible to set everything in a Python code so I don't have to change anything on a clients PC?

Comment: Why not run the program with a cron job?

Comment: @Martin I haven't heard about a cron job since now. Do you think It's a best way to do that?

Comment: In Posix, `man crontab`

Comment: @LittleQ It will work on windows

Comment: @Milan `Task Scheduler` on windows

Answer (score 1):

Since you are on Windows, consider using the `SCHTASKS` command:

> Schedules commands and programs to run periodically or at a
>   specific time. Adds and removes tasks from the schedule, starts and
>   stops tasks on demand, and displays and changes scheduled tasks.

Your command should look like:

```
schtasks /create /tn <TaskName> /tr <TaskRun> /sc hourly [/mo {1 - 23}] [/st <HH:MM>] [/sd <StartDate>] [/ed <EndDate>]
```

`/mo` is the repeat interval

For the complete documentation refer to:
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/cc725744.aspx

Answer (score 0):

**Only** if you do not have access to clients PC , you can do something like - calculate the time now using `datetime` library , then take the different between the next time you want to run the program and `now` , then sleep for that much amount of seconds using `time.sleep` . When you wake up , again run whatever you want , and then again do same thing calculate time between now and next time you want to run the program.

Example code -

```
from datetime import datetime
import time
while True:
    nw = datetime.now()
    nw
    >> datetime.datetime(2015, 6, 22, 17, 57, 5, 668002)
    t = datetime(nw.year,nw.month,nw.day,22,0,0,0) # this is where you calculate next time you want to run the program.
    t
    >> datetime.datetime(2015, 6, 22, 22, 0)
    td = t - nw
    td.seconds
    >> 14574
    time.sleep(14574)
    #<do your stuff>
```

Please note in above code , `>>` indicates the printed value of the previous statements, and they are not part of the code.

Though I am not sure, if there are any side-effects (bad-effects) of making a process sleep for very long.

If you have access to client's PC , or can make him run a task scheduler or in unix , cronjob , consider that as the better option.